# How to print using cmd only with the name of the printer?

Tags: windows, command-line, printer

I try to print from the command line specifying only the name of the printer:

```
C:\> print file.txt /D:epson
```

The following message is displayed:

> The epson device can not be initialized

I require that it can be printed **only by specifying the name of the printer**, or that it detects the printer by default.

It's possible?

Some comment

Comment: Not possible. `/d` specifies a device (not a printer name) where `device` is either a local printer (`LPTx`, `COMx`) or a network printer by its sharename (`\\servername\print_share`). See [Print - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/print.html)

Comment: How would you specify local printer (LPTx, COMx), without sharing the printer
?:
I have a dot matrix printer connected by USB ,           
thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 1):

The method you suggest does not work under Windows. Nor can you send the file to a USB port.

Before I explain how to achieve what you want, I'll start by assuming the printer actually understands plain text. As your comment says it's a dot matrix printer, it probably does. However, most low-cost USB inkjet and laser printers do not, so in that case the rest of my answer is irrelevant.

Start by sharing the printer on the PC that it is connected to. Do this even if only that PC will ever need to print to it. Make a note of the share-name. Also note the PC's host-name.

Now issue the following command from a DOS prompt:

NET USE LPT1: \host-name\printer-share-name /persistent:yes

After this you should be able to print your file by typing:

PRINT /D:LPT1 file.txt

You can also use COPY, TYPE and any other command that lets you send a file to a device.